# Stream image format conversions and resizing in Java

Tags: java, type-conversion, png, jpeg, encoder

So, lets say I want to recode some PNG to JPEG in Java. The image has extreme resolution, lets say for example 10 000 x 10 000px. Using "standard" Java image API Writers and Reader, you need at some point to have entire image decoded in RAM, which takes extreme amount of RAM space (hundreds of MB). I have been looking how other tools do this, and I found that ImageMagick uses disk pixel storage, but this seems to by way too slower for my needs. So what I need is tru streaming recoder. And by true streaming I mean read and process data by chuncks or bins, not just give stream as input but decode it whole beforehand.

Now,  first the theory behind - is it even possible, given JPEG and PNG algorithms, to do this using streams, or lets say in bins of data? So there is no need to have entire image encoded in memory(or other storage)? In JPEG compression, first few stages could be done in streams, but I believe Huffman encoding needs to build entire tree of value probabilities after quantization, therefore it needs to analyze whole image - so whole image needs to be decoded beforehand, or somehow on demand by regions.

And the golden question, if above could be achieved, is there any Java library that can actually work in this way? And save large amount of RAM?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/thumbnailator/ ? or Thumbnails.of("large-picture.png")
        .scale(1.0)
        .outputFormat("jpg")
        .toOutputStream(os);

Comment: "No need to access the Image I/O API and manually manipulate BufferedImages through Graphics2D objects. Thumbnailator does all of that for you." - this seems it is not streaming, the fact that you can get output stream does not make the process of conversion streaming.

Comment: Thumbnailator does not currently support the "streaming" as @B.Gen.Jack.O.Neill intends. However, the Image I/O API does not require that the entire image be read into memory first -- if the `ImageReader` supports it, it is possible to load parts of an image and perform operations, discard that portion and move on to the next. I intend to support that type of operation in Thumbnailator in the future, but it does require quite a bit of re-designing to support it.

Answer (score 1):

If I create a 10,000 x 10,000 PNG file, full of incompressible noise, with ImageMagick like this:

```
convert -size 10000x10000 xc:gray +noise random image.png
```

I see ImageMagick uses 675M of RAM to create the resulting 572MB file.

I can convert it to a JPEG with `vips` like this:

```
vips im_copy image.png output.jpg
```

and `vips` uses no more than 100MB of RAM while converting, and takes 7 seconds on a reasonable spec iMac around 4 years old - albeit with SSD.

Answer (score 1):

I have thought about this for a while, and I would really like to implement such a library. Unfortunately, it's not that easy. Different image formats  store pixels in different ways. PNG or GIFs may be interlaced. JPEGs may be progressive (multiple scans). TIFFs are often striped or tiled. BMPs are usually stored bottom up. PSDs are channeled. Etc.

Because of this, the minimum amount of data you have to read to recode to a different format, may in worst case be the entire image (or maybe not, if the format supports random access and you can live with a lot of `seek`ing back and forth)... Resampling (scaling) the image to a new file using the same format would probably work in most cases though (probably not so good for progressive JPEGs, unless you can resample each scan separately).

If you can live with disk buffer though, as the second best option, I have created some classes that allows for `BufferedImage`s to be backed by nio  `MappedByteBuffer`s (memory-mapped file `Buffer`s, kind of like virtual memory). While performance isn't really like in-memory images, it's also not entirely useless. Have a look at [`MappedImageFactory`](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/sandbox/sandbox-common/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/image/MappedImageFactory.java) and [`MappedFileBuffer`](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/sandbox/sandbox-common/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/image/MappedFileBuffer.java).

Answer (score 0):

I've written a PNG encoder/decoder that does that (read and write progressively, which only requires to store a row in memory) for PNG format: [PNGJ](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngj/)

I don't know if there is something similar with JPEG